# Symfony 2 entity form field

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a twig template with an entity field, and when I use it twice, it doesn’t work. For exemple:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Secondary</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {% if entity.category and entity.category.parent %}
            <span style="margin-right:5px;">{{ entity.category.parent.name }} ›</span>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.categories) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.categories) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Secondary</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {% if entity.category and entity.category.parent %}
            <span style="margin-right:5px;">{{ entity.category.parent.name }} ›</span>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.categories) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.categories) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Secondary 2</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {% if entity.category and entity.category.parent %}
            <span style="margin-right:5px;">{{ entity.category.parent.name }} ›</span>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.categories) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.categories) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The label is written but I can’t get the select tag box. After research, I conclude that it’s impossible to duplicate an entity?

Comment: you need to use a [form collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: When a I do that I get :
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class

Comment: you need to create a form, to hold the forms for the entity. that way you can specify a form for more than one instance of the entity type